# How to figure out if search enabled in Sharepoint using the API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to figure out with the API if a document library/list is allowed for search:

[image]

Is there a field/endpoint I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter is called `NoCrawl` (`NoCrawl` to `yes` means `no` allowed for search).

To *get* the current value, a simple GET request is enough:

```
https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists(guid'{list_guid}')
```

You can also *change* this value by API with the REST API (with a POST method and an XML body) or with a PowerShell script (CSOM or Pnp).

**Sample for REST API:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#working-with-lists-by-using-rest

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists(guid'{list_guid}')
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
Content-Type: "application/json"

{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.List"
  },
  "NoCrawl": true
}
```

**Sample with PowerShell:**
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/10/sharepoint-online-remove-list-from-search-crawl.html

Comment: Do you know if this can be done using Graph API? Thanks

Comment: No, I don't think so. Graph API for list cannot patch an existing list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-1.0